# I need some help understanding proofs for an upside-down cycloid being the tautochrone curve. Could someone show me or point me to a simple proof?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, education, mathematical-physics

The tautochrone curve has fascinated me since I first heard about it and I want to share it with my Calculus class as an end of the year project. I think something similar to this ([Demonstrating that a cycloid solves the Tautochrone Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/563937)) would suffice. I don't completely understand it myself, so that is a little bit of a problem. It is an AP calculus BC course in high school, so the kids are for the most part unmotivated and I want to help them realize how cool it can be. I don't need anything super complicated, just something simple enough for high schoolers with Calulus 2 under their belt to understand. Thank you so much!

Comment: So what exactly do you want? A proof or an explanation of it?

Comment: Sorry I probably should have made that more clear. I need a (if possible) proof so that I can better explain it to a high school class.

Comment: Ah. I might put a bounty on this question if it is not answered by the time I get 1050+ rep.

Comment: How do I put a bounty on it? Sorry, I'm new to the sight.

Comment: @ArzaHelm, only users with more than 75  "rep" can place bounties.  When the opportunity opens up after a certain amount of time has passed, SalmonKiller can place one automatically.

Comment: You need to have enough reputation to do that. More on it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: ok that makes sense. Thank you guys!

Comment: There's a straightforward proof in the first chapter of George Simmons' Differential Equations text.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TautochroneProblem.html

Answer (score 1):

As I recall,
Polya's
"Mathematics and Plausible Reasoning, vol 1"
has a good discussion of this.
Look in chapter 9, "Physical Mathematics."